# Python C APi Deep Copy

Tags: python, c, copy

How do I do a deep copy of a python object using the C API? I know I can use copy.deepcopy, but I'd prefer to use the C API if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality of `copy.deepcopy()` is [completely written in Python](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Lib/copy.py?view=markup).  I don't think they would have done this if there was a single C call to achieve the same thing, so my guess is you will have to call `copy.deepcopy()`.

Comment: Thanks I thought taht might be the case. Thanks anyway!